# How to get the Id of a inserted record in Visual workflow

Tags: flow

I have to insert 2 records via visual flow. First I need to insert Account after that need to created contact associate to the created account. For this I need to hold the Id of account in a variable and when contact is created need to include account id. But how can I capture account id into a variable. Please guide me or please provide me the best way to get the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First create a variable for your flow. Items in the flow need to be unique. So I like to use prefixes. Give it a name like var_Account_id

When you have the insert action for Account in your flow, there is an option to assign the return ID to a flow variable. You need to use that with the var_Account_id variable.

For each contact you create, in the AccountId field, you simply assign the variable as the value.

[I will try to follow up with screen shots a little later, but these are the basic steps you need to follow.]

Comment: thanks, it works for me. Can you please help me how to calculate the date. 
eg : I want to pick current date and add 30 days to it.

Comment: Solved by adding value in Assignment element.